# Move a certain elements in 2D Array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Given a 2d array. If `[i][0] == name`, how do I move it to last element of the array?

```
String[][] array2d = [ [continents, name, Asia, Europe, Africa, Australia, South America, North America, Antartica],
 [profession, Teacher, Doctor, Lawyer],
 [brand, Apple, Samsung],
[name, Lisa, Peter, Sam, Jake],
[profession, Engineer, Professor, Dentist, Driver],
 [sex, value, Male, Female],
 [exp, value, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]]
```

My desired output is

```
[ [continents, name, Asia, Europe, Africa, Australia, South America, North America, Antartica],
 [profession, Teacher, Doctor, Lawyer],
 [brand, Apple, Samsung],
 [profession, Engineer, Professor, Dentist, Driver],
 [sex, value, Male, Female],
 [exp, value, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6],
[name, Lisa, Peter, Sam, Jake]
]
```

Below are the codes

```
 String[][] newArray =new String[array2d.length][];

     for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; ++i) {
         newArray[i] = new String[array2d[i].length];
         for (int j = 0; j < newArray[i].length; ++j) {
             if (array2d[i][0] != "name") {
                 newArray[i][j] = array2d[i][j];
             }
         }
      }
```

However, the output is

```
[[continents, name, Asia, Europe, Africa, Australia, South America, North America, Antartica],
 [profession, Teacher, Doctor, Lawyer],
 [brand, Apple, Samsung],
 [null, null, null, null, null],
 [profession, Engineer, Professor, Dentist, Driver],
 [sex, value, Male, Female],
 [exp, value, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]]
```

Thank you!

Comment: what have you tried? please post your code..

Comment: can you post your code which you tried to perform the mentioned operation?

Comment: check if [i][0] == name if it is then exchange  it with the last element and keep one pointer for last element decrease this pointer every time you exchange one element

Comment: @Kartik I have posted the code. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @JavaLearner1 I have posted the code. Please take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First backup last element ( it is a 1d array) ,deep copy your arrays last element to a tempary variable as var) then copy your selected ( it is a 1d array  )element to the last element of the array. At last copy backed up last element to the array's your selected element.
this is the pseudo code.

```
if(array[i][0] == name){  

   var = deepCopy(array[last]
   array[last] = deepCopy(array[i])
   array[i] = var

}
```

[This link](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/deepCopying.htm) is about deep Copy

Comment: the pseudo code given is applicable to 1d array? What I have is a 2d array, should I convert to 1d array?

Comment: No your 2d arrays selected element is 1d array. that's what i mean.

Comment: this can be done after selecting the element in 2d array (which is a 1d array).

Comment: in your case arrays type is String so  var is a type of String [ ], eg : - String [ ]  var = array2d[i]

Answer (score 2):

You can try in this way... You only need to rearrange array references

```
   package testProgram;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] array = new String[7][];
        array[0] = new String[] { "continents", "Asia", "Europe", "Africa", "Australia", "South America",
                "North America" };
        array[1] = new String[] { "profession", "teacher", "doctor", "lawyer" };
        array[2] = new String[] { "brand", "apple", "samsung" };
        array[3] = new String[] { "name", "lisa", "peter", "sam", "jack" };
        array[4] = new String[] { "profession", "engineer", "Professor", "Dentist", "Driver" };
        array[5] = new String[] { "sex", "value", "male", "female" };
        array[6] = new String[] { "exp", "value", "1", "2", "3", "4" };

        int index = sc.nextInt();
        //shuffling array references
        String[] tempReference = array[index - 1];
        for (int i = index - 1; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
        }
        array[array.length - 1] = tempReference;

        for (String[] tempArray : array) {
            for (String s : tempArray) {
                System.out.print(s + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assuming that "name" will always be at index 3. Try writing the code again without hard-coding `array[3]`.

Comment: now you are asking the user for the index.. this is still hard-coding.. as the OP mentioned, you need to traverse the array to look for an item where `[i][0] == name`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Initialize
    String[][] arr = new String[][]{
            new String[]{"continents", "abc"},
            new String[]{"name", "test"},
            new String[]{"something", "test something"},
    };

    int indexOfNameArray = -1;

    //Continuous swap logic
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (indexOfNameArray > -1 && indexOfNameArray < arr.length - 1) {
            String[] temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
            arr[i - 1] = temp;
            indexOfNameArray = i;
        } else if (arr[i][0].equals("name")) {
            indexOfNameArray = i;
        }
    }

    //To display output
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```